# Segmentation Fault with C List when not using global List

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, initialization, singly-linked-list

I have written some code creating a singly linked list and then converting it to a dynamic array in C.

The code works just fine if I only create a global variable for the list header. If I want to create the list in my main function, however, I always get a segmentation fault.

The code below works just fine as soon as I create a global list variable instead and remove the list as parameter from all functions.

Can anyone tell me why this won't work if I want to pass the list as a parameter to the function and thus be able to create multiple lists?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct NodeStruct* Node;
typedef struct NodeStruct {
Node next;
int val;
} NodeStruct;
typedef Node List;



Node newNode(int x){
    Node n = (Node)malloc(sizeof(NodeStruct));
    if(n!=NULL){
        n->val = x;
        n->next = NULL;
        return n;
    }
    else{
        printf("ERROR: Could not allocate memory!\n");
    }
    exit(1);
}

void prepend(List l, Node node){
    if (l == NULL) l = node;
    else{
        node->next = l;
        l = node;
    }
}

void printList(List l){
    if(l!=NULL){
        Node n = l;
        while(n->next != NULL){
            printf("%d, ", n->val);
            n = n->next;
        }
        printf("%d\n", n->val);
    }
    else{
        printf("ERROR: List empty!\n");
    }
}



/*=============================*/

int* arrOf(List l){
    if(l==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: List empty\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int size = 0;
    Node n = l;
    while(n!=NULL){
        size++; 
        n = n->next;
    }
    
    int* arr = (int*)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(int));
    n = l;
    int i = 0;
    arr[i++] = size;
    while(n != NULL){
        arr[i++] = n->val;
        n = n->next;
    }
    printf("Returning Array\n");
    return arr;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    List l;
    
    prepend(l, newNode(5));
    prepend(l, newNode(6));
    prepend(l, newNode(7));
    prepend(l, newNode(8));
    prepend(l, newNode(9));
    prepend(l, newNode(4));
   
    printList(l);
    printf("\n===========================================\n");
    
    int* arr = arrOf(l);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize `List l` in `main`, you are not assigning a default value. It is stored on the stack and not initialized. This means the value is undefined and not necessarily null.

When you are creating `List l` globally, the variable is stored in the bss segment and initialized with null.

Change your declaration of `List l` to:

```c
List l = NULL;
```

Comment: In modern C++, you can do `List l = nullptr;` or `List l{};` instead of using that C macro.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I still had to turn the function from void into returning the List at the end but then everything worked.

Modern C++ comes way easier to me. This is for an exam in C tho

Comment: That's true, but OP is using C, not C++. I agree that your suggestion is better style for C++, though. :)

Comment: @maxkremsner glad to help!

Comment: @MartinFink Sorry, not sure why I had C++ in mind here.

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
void prepend(List l, Node node){
    if (l == NULL) l = node;
    else{
        node->next = l;
        l = node;
    }
}
```

deals with a copy of the value of the pointer `l` declared in main

```
List l;
```

that moreover was not initialized.

So changing of the copy in these statements within the function

```
if (l == NULL) l = node;
//...
l = node;
```

does not influence on the original value of the pointer declared in main.

You have to write at least like

```
void prepend(List *l, Node node){
        node->next = *l;
        *l = node;
}
```

and in main

```
List l = NULL;
```

The function can be called like

```
prepend( &l, newNode(5) );
```

That is the pointer to the head node must be passed to the function by reference.

Also you need to free all the dynamically allocated memory for the list and the array.

Comment: Oh sweet there was the second problem. I knew I had to pass a pointer to the list as argument somehow.